# How to place a true fixed position div inside fixed position div

Tags: html, css, transform

I've got a modal style I'm using from http://tympanus.net/codrops/ but I've created a custom close button (.md-close) that I want to be truly fixed in the top right as the user scrolls the content of the modal window.

Code here: http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/upzrB

Right now when you scroll, .md-close leaves the visible area, making it hard to close without scrolling up. How can I force this to stay put?

I realize this is something to do with the `position` property but I've tried every possible combination of the parents and children. Might this have something to do with the `transform` property I'm using?

Any help?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/BuaW4/ - it seems it works as you want it to (in Chrome at least). Also please paste the code here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Full css i used :

or live : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lynBm

```
.md-close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3vw;
    right: 3vw;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    background: black;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    display: block;
    background: blue url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Close.svg/120px-VisualEditor_-_Icon_-_Close.svg.png);
    background-size: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.md-trigger {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  margin: 100px auto;

}

.md-modal {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100000000000px;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: none;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

.md-content {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10% !important;
}

.md-show.md-effect-12 ~ .md-overlay {
  background-color: black;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding a max-height of `100vh` to .md-content